# JPA: How do I create a field of same type as Entity?

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa

My class looks like

```
@Entity
public class Version extends MutableEntity {
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private VersionType type;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private VersionStatus status;
    @Column(nullable = true)
    private DateTime publishedOn;
    @Column(nullable = true)
    private DateTime retiredOn;
    @Column
    private Version parentVersion;
```

I want to have a `parentVersion` of same type as `Version`, but my test fails

```
@Test
public void testVersion() {
    Version version = new Version("testVersion", VersionType.MAJOR);
    version = crudService.create(version);
    assertNotNull(version.getId());
}
```

and I see error as

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: com.myorg.project.versioning.entities.Version, at table: Version, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(parentVersion)]
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

It is not basic attribute. It is relation because value is other entity. Consequently [@ManyToOne](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/ManyToOne.html) annotation should be used:

```
@ManyToOne
private Version parentVersion;
```

If bidirectional relationship is needed (parent knowing childrens), that can be done by adding following:

```
@OneToMany (mappedBy = "parentVersion")
private List<Version> childVersions;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your are missing some annotations at `parentVersion`. Hibernate does not know how to map this column in the DB.

Add `@JoinColumn` to your field and hibernate will use its @Id field.